# Only allow external PostgreSQL connections for specific database

Tags: postgresql

I've got a Postgres server that's configured to only allow connections from localhost. I like that.

However, I have a situation where I need to run a database that is accessible from something other than localhost.

Is there any way to set this sort of configuration on a **per-database** level?

Comment: I'm curious why allowing _only_ external connections is preferential.  It essentially means you can't properly administer the database from the server it's running on.

Comment: I guess I wasn't clear - I don't want to disallow localhost, only **additionally** allow other sources.

Comment: Yeah, but that's not what the title says, which is the reason I asked.  What you're really asking is "Allow external connections, but only for a specific database".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is pretty easy to do.

Just find the pg_hba.conf file your Postgres uses  (Mine is in /etc/postgresql/8.4/main but yours may differ, but its the same directory as postgresql.conf is in), and add the appropriate line, for example

> host dbname  all 1.2.3.4 md5

Will allow any user at 1.2.3.4 to connect to the the database dbname using md5 authentication.

You may need to adjust your firewall rules to allow port 5432 (assuming you run on the default port) through from that machine to your server.